# Syntax for nested If statements

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction

This seems an awfully long-winded way to achieve the following:

```
Fold[
    If[sol < Part[#2, 1], 
        Evaluate[Part[#2, 2]], 
        Evaluate[If[ListQ[#], Part[#, 1], #]]
    ] &,
    Part[#, 1], Rest[#]
]   &@
    Reverse[
        Partition[
            Take[ToExpression[Alphabet[]], 9], 
        UpTo[2]
        ]
    ]

(*
    If[sol < a, b, If[sol < c, d, If[sol < e, f, If[sol < g, h, i]]]]
*)
```

What is the recommended construction for nested `If` statements? I'm not sure why the `Evaluate` is needed.

Comment: Consider avoiding nested If altogether and going with one of [`Switch`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Switch.html) or [`Which`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Which.html) or [`Piecewise`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html). What is your code trying to do? I can't quite follow it.

Comment: @MarcoB Tried to use `Switch` be used with `<`, but my syntax clearly wrong..

Comment: Could you add what you tried to the OP?

Comment: See if this works the same: `Which @@ (Riffle[sol < # & @@@ Most@Reverse@alist, 
    Last /@ Most@Reverse@alist]~Join~{True}~Join~First@alist)` where `alist = Reverse[Partition[Take[ToExpression[Alphabet[]], 9], UpTo[2]]]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how I would have done it:

```
Piecewise[
   {#2, sol < #} & @@@ Partition[#, 2],
   Last@#
   ] &@Take[Symbol /@ Alphabet[], 9]
```

[image]

If you insist on using `If`, I would have used the following variant of your code:

```
Fold[
    if[sol < #2[[1]], #2[[2]], #] &,
    Last@#,
    Reverse@Partition[#, 2]
    ] &@Take[Symbol /@ Alphabet[], 9] /.
  if -> If
(* If[sol < a, b, If[sol < c, d, If[sol < e, f, If[sol < g, h, i]]]] *)
```

The main difference is the use of the shorthand syntax for `Part` (`a[[b]]` instead of `Part[a,b]`), and the use of a helper symbol `if` that is only replaced by `If` at the end. This removes the need for the `Evaluate` calls in the arguments to `If`

Comment: thanks for removing the necessity to evaluate by replacing `if`